# Compilation error with generic types with cyclic generic dependencies

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code:

```
public abstract class Animal<A extends Cage<? extends Animal<A>>>
{
    private A cage;

    public A getCage()
    {
        return this.cage;
    }

    public void setCage(final A cage)
    {
         this.cage = cage;
    }
}

public abstract class Cage<A extends Animal<? extends Cage<A>>>
{
    private List<A> animals;

    public void addAnimal(final A animal)
    {
        if (animal != null)
        {
            animal.setCage(this);

            if (this.animals == null)
            {
                this.animals = new ArrayList<A>();
            }

            this.animals.add(animal);
        }
    }
}
```

These classes are further extended by other classes.

This code fails to compile at the line

```
animal.setCage(this);
```

Any thoughts on why this code does not compile and how it can be fixed?  We are using Java 1.6.

Comment: Could you try with: **1°)** `class Animal<A extends Cage<C, A>, C extends Animal<A, C>>` ; **2°)** `class Cage<A extends Animal<C, A>, C extends Cage<A, C>>` ; **3°)** `animal.setCage((C) this);`?

Comment: Thanks @sp00m, this works!  Brilliant stuff.  If you add this as an answer, I will accept it so that you get the credit for suggesting this.

Comment: You're welcome, I've made a *real* answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should suit your needs:

```
public abstract class Animal<A extends Cage<C, A>, C extends Animal<A, C>> {

    private A cage;

    public A getCage() {
        return this.cage;
    }

    public void setCage(final A cage) {
        this.cage = cage;
    }

}

public abstract class Cage<A extends Animal<C, A>, C extends Cage<A, C>> {

    private List<A> animals;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void addAnimal(final A animal) {
        if (animal != null) {
            animal.setCage((C) this);
            if (this.animals == null) {
                this.animals = new ArrayList<A>();
            }
            this.animals.add(animal);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @newacct I guess `this` is whatever castable to `C`, am I wrong? Or in what case `this` could be of another type than `C`?

Comment: for example, `class Dog extends Animal<DogCage, Dog>`, `class DogCage extends Cage<Dog, DogCage>`, and `class AnotherDogCage extends Cage<Dog, DogCage>`

Answer (score 0):

Effectively you're trying to say that A in both classes is the same, which it isn't, and hence it won't compile.

I think you ought to review exactly why you need generics here, I think this could certainly be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

For the methods you have shown, this seems sufficient:

```
public abstract class Animal<C> {

    private C cage;

    public C getCage() {
        return this.cage;
    }

    public void setCage(final C cage) {
        this.cage = cage;
    }

}

public abstract class Cage<A extends Animal<C>, C> {

    private List<A> animals;

    public abstract C getThis();

    public void addAnimal(final A animal) {
        if (animal != null) {
            animal.setCage(getThis());
            if (this.animals == null) {
                this.animals = new ArrayList<A>();
            }
            this.animals.add(animal);
        }
    }

}

public class CatCage extends Cage<Cat, CatCage> {
    @Override
    public CatCage getThis() { return this; }
}
```